# MVC index method with change to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I want to know the best way of writing an index method in MVC when we need to make changes to the model before passing it to the view.

I picked up a technique from somewhere where you can pass in the model you intend to pass to your view, and make changes to it, but we have noticed that model binding kicks in when passing to the index method, and validation fires, when there is no need for it to because it is the initial load.

For example, which is more correct:

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    model.SomeProperty = "MyNewValue";

    return base.Index(model);
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

    model.SomeProperty = "MyNewValue";

    return base.Index(model);
}
```

and is there anything I should know about the implications of using either one?

Answer (score 0):

With initial loads, the latter makes more sense. Controllers in MVC are newed up each and every single time you use them. There is no persistence whatsoever. With the first option, HTTP requests need some pre-existing knowledge of your API. So, the recommendation is to have the view model come from a persistence layer.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = /* persistence layer */
    vm.SomeProperty = "NewVal";
    return View(vm);
}
```